# JPEG vs RAW - how big is the difference

Tags: jpeg, raw-vs-jpeg

I've read some of the questions and answers on here but they are all years old. (some of them over 10 years ago)

In this day and age, is there still a significant difference in quality of the image between JPEG and RAW, and if so, how big is that difference? And is there a difference between shooting for digital use vs shooting for print? Is RAW for example much better for print, while for digital the difference is smaller?

Comment: The answer is still the same as it was. JPEGs are still JPEGs and have only 8 bit range.

Comment: The key (in my interpretation) is that RAW isn't an image at all. It _must_ be post-processed. You can post-process JPEGs too of course (or not), but a RAW file gives you much more to work with.